# Replace text with variable

Tags: docusignapi

I'd like to use the bulk uploader to override text in a document. E.g. I could have JOB_TITLE in the document and this should be replaced with the contents of the CSV file. I can see how I can put the fields in but it doesn't make space for long titles - text goes over the existing text.

How can I replace a tag with a long string and still have everything fit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You specify an absolute (i.e., specific) width when you place a new field (tab) in a document, and DocuSign reserves exactly that much space for the field value, irrespective of the location of surrounding text in the document. As it sounds like you're experiencing, if the field value you specify exceeds the space that's been reserved for that field in the document, the value will be written in its entirety to the document, overlapping any adjacent text located to the right of the field.

Therefore, if possible, it's best to format/arrange your document contents in such a way that any variable length fields are placed at the end of their own line, rather than 'inline' within a sentence (in close proximity to other text).

For example, instead of contents like this:

***We are pleased to offer you the position of [JOB_TITLE] with a salary of [SALARY], beginning on [START_DATE].***

You could instead arrange things more like this:

***We are pleased to offer you the following position:***

***Title: [JOB_TITLE]***

***Salary: [SALARY]***

***Start Date: [START_DATE]***

That way, regardless of the length of JOB_TITLE, SALARY, or START_DATE (within reason, of course), the final document will be formatted nicely.